# символ _ и результат replace golang

Tags: регулярные-выражения, golang

Добрый вечер. подскажите пожалуйста
как экранировать символ _ в случаи результата замены replace ?

```
reg := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:\/)([^\/]+)(\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))`)
result := reg.ReplaceAllString("/test1/test2/test3/start.end.jpg", "/min/$1 _min$2")
```

result содержит /test1/test2/test3/min/start.end _min.jpg ,а нужно /test1/test2/test3/min/start.end_min.jpg

```
result := reg.ReplaceAllString("/test1/test2/test3/start.end.jpg", "/min/$1_min$2")
```

в этом случаи результат такой /test1/test2/test3/min/.jpg

вот собственно сам код в действии https://play.golang.org/p/l0cO3ZDRa2

как быть? (заранее благодарен)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```
reg := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:\/)([^\/]+)(\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))`)
result := reg.ReplaceAllString("/test1/test2/test3/start.end.jpg", "/min/${1}_min${2}")
```

Ссылка на [код](https://play.golang.org/p/FRD8P1LTw3)

Comment: Mikhail, спасибо большое)

Comment: @Jenyokcoder: Можно поправить и так: `regexp.MustCompile(\`/([^/]+)(\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))\`)`, т.к. в регулярных выражениях в Go не используются разделители.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема здесь совсем не в экранировании символа `_`, его не нужно экранировать ни в регулярном выражении, ни в шаблоне замены. Проблема в том, что в шаблоне замены после `$` все буквы, цифры и знак `_` трактуются как имя переменной/ссылки. Т.е. тут `"/min/$1_min$2"` = `"/min/${1_min}$2"`, а так как ссылки с именем `1_min` не задано (в регулярном выражении нет именной захватывающей подмаски (группы) с именем `1_min`), `${1_min}` представляет собой пустую строку в данном случае.

См. описание [`Regexp.ReplaceAllString`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.ReplaceAllString):

> Inside repl, $ signs are interpreted as in Expand, so for instance $1 represents the text of the first submatch. (= В аргументе `repl` **символы `$` интерпретируются как в методе `Expand`**, поэтому, например, `$1` содержит текст первой захватывающей подмаски.)

См. описание метода [`Regexp.Expand`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.Expand) (в моём переводе):

> В шаблоне переменная определяется с помощью подстроки вида `$name` или `${имя}`, где `имя` — это непустая последовательность букв, цифр и символов подчёркивания. Числовое имя, такое как `$1`, ссылается на подсовпадение с соответствующим индексом. Другие имена ссылаются на значения именных захватывающих подмасок (групп) вида `(?P<name>...)`. **Ссылка на несуществующие индекс или имя заменяется пустой строкой**.
> Если ссылка задана в виде `$имя`, длина `имени` задаётся максимальным количеством символов после знака `$`: `$1x` равно `${1x}`, а не `${1}x`, а также `$10` равно `${10}`, а не `${1}0`.
> Чтобы вставить символ `$` в результат, используйте `$$` в шаблоне замены.

Итак, чтобы решить проблему, достаточно заменить `$1` на `${1}`. Стоит отметить, что прямой слеш не нужно экранировать в регулярных выражениях в Go, так как `/` не является специальным оператором регулярных выражений:

```
reg := regexp.MustCompile(`/([^/]+)(\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))`)
result := reg.ReplaceAllString("/test1/test2/test3/start.end.jpg", "/min/${1}_min$2")
```

Или используйте именные группы (для наглядности и читабельности):

```
reg2 := regexp.MustCompile(`/(?P<last_part>[^/]+)(?P<ext>\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))`)
result2 := reg2.ReplaceAllString("/test1/test2/test3/start.end.jpg", "/min/${last_part}_min${ext}")
```

См. [Go-демо](https://play.golang.org/p/-YcFv2Jw3a):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    // Числовые подмаски (группы)
    reg := regexp.MustCompile(`/([^/]+)(\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))`)
    result := reg.ReplaceAllString("/test1/test2/test3/start.end.jpg", "/min/${1}_min$2")
    fmt.Println(result)
    // => /test1/test2/test3/min/start.end_min.jpg

    // Именные подмаски (группы)
    reg2 := regexp.MustCompile(`/(?P<last_part>[^/]+)(?P<ext>\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif))`)
    result2 := reg2.ReplaceAllString("/test1/test2/test3/start.end.jpg", "/min/${last_part}_min${ext}")
    fmt.Println(result2)
    // => /test1/test2/test3/min/start.end_min.jpg
}
```